# Hide email addresses from To field when sending to multiple recipients

Tags: email, thunderbird

I am using Thunderbird hooked up with a Gmail account and want to know how to send emails to a group of people but not have them all see each other's email addresses.

I want to send people some emails and I usually have to send them out one at a time since I don't want other people to see their emails.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the BCC (blind carbon copy) line to insert the email addresses. The recipients will not be able to see who the other recipients are.

Comment: Cool. So I can just use BCC and not have a To line then?

Comment: Yes, that's right.